Place a top bar above a background image using SwiftUI
I want the background image and the green UI element to be at the top of the screen, but with the code below the green UI elements in the middle.
code:
struct AppointmentStep1: View {

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background image
            Image("home_bg")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .tint(.white)
                            .padding(.trailing, 6)
                    }

                    Text("Appointment")
                        .font(.calibriRegular(with: 20))
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(16)
            }
            .background(
                Color.appGreen2
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            )

           Spacer()
        }
    }
}

o/p: how to move the green view to top
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
EDIT:

this is my background image: please try with this bg.. i got same o/p always


try moving your .background(Color.appGreen2.ignoresSafeArea()) and Spacer()
inside the VStack, just after the .padding(16)

@workingdogsupportUkraine, with this code i got like above screen.. added in post edit section.. green colour going inside of top –

The reason why you only see a thin green bar at the top of your second screenshot is because the background image is inside the ZStack and it is being scaled to fill. This increases the size of the ZStack to the size of the image, which includes off-screen content.
I would suggest applying the image using .background, then you don't even need a ZStack. Also:

Apply maxHeight: .infinity to the VStack, so that it fills the full screen height.
Use alignment: .top, so that the green bar appears at the top of the screen.
You don't need to apply .ignoresSafeArea() to the green background, because this happens by default. See background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:).

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Button  {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .tint(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 6)
            }

            Text("Appointment")
                .font(.calibriRegular(with: 20))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(16)
        .background(.appGreen2)
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    .background {
        Image("home_bg")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}



To achieve the result I presume you expect, first of all you need to move Spacer from ZStack to VStack. Here's the edited code snippet for your reference:
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Image("home_bg")
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFill()
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    VStack {
      HStack {
        Button { dismiss() } label: {
          Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
            .font(.system(size: 25.0))
            .tint(.white)
            .padding(.trailing, 6.0)
          }
          Text("Appointment")
            .font(.calibriRegular(with: 20))
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
          Spacer()
        }
          .padding(.vertical, 16.0)
          .padding(.horizontal, 32.0)
          .background(
            Color
              .appGreen2
              .ignoresSafeArea()
          )
      Spacer() // <– This one.
    }
  }
}

Here's the result:

(On the screenshot you see another background image and another green colour, because I obviously don't have your non-standard assets.)
I also played with the paddings of Button to fix them a bit—perhaps this is another thing you want to fix.

i am still getting the same issue.. can u plz try my home_bg background.. is my bg is problem?
